# Sharepoint check in multiple items

Tags: sharepoint, checkout

I have just moved a batch of documents to sharepoint using webdav, but to my surprise, they are now all checked out. Click-by-click checking-in 100 documents seems a bit too timetaking for me.

Doesn't sharepoint have a method for checking all documents in a directory and its children?

Answer (score 1):

You can check in multiple documents with SharePoint Designer.
Open the site with SPD. Use the menu on the left to browse to your library. Select all the documents, then right click. There's an entry in the contextual menu in order to check in the documents.